# Linear System Constraint Optimization with Integer Solutions

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, or-tools

I am interested in solving the following optimization problem and obtaining the lowest positive integer coefficients:

```
min(x1 + x2 + x3)
s.t. 
2x1 – 2x3 = 0
2x2 – x3 = 0
```

Since the number of equations do not match the number of variables, I also add the constraint that `x1 = 1`. Using the documentation from [ortools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/mip_var_array), I adapted the code as follows:

```
mat = np.array([[2,0,-2],[0,2,-1]])
def create_data_model(mat):
    num_rows, num_vars =mat.shape
    data = {}
    data['constraint_coeffs'] = [
          [2, 0, -2],
          [0, 2, -1],
          [1, 0, 0],
      ]
    data['bounds'] = [0, 0, 1]
    data['obj_coeffs'] = [1, 1, 1]
    data['num_vars'] = num_vars
    offset = np.max((num_rows, num_vars))-np.min((num_rows, num_vars))
    data['num_constraints'] = num_rows+offset
    return data

data=create_data_model(mat)
infinity = solver.infinity()
x = {}
for j in range(data['num_vars']):
    x[j] = solver.IntVar(0, infinity, 'x[%i]' % j)
print('Number of variables =', solver.NumVariables())

for i in range(data['num_constraints']):
    constraint = solver.RowConstraint(0, data['bounds'][i], '')
    for j in range(data['num_vars']):
        constraint.SetCoefficient(x[j], data['constraint_coeffs'][i][j])

print('Number of constraints =', solver.NumConstraints())

objective = solver.Objective()
for j in range(data['num_vars']):
    objective.SetCoefficient(x[j], data['obj_coeffs'][j])
objective.SetMinimization()

if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
    for j in range(data['num_vars']):
        print(x[j].name(), ' = ', x[j].solution_value())
    print()
    print('Problem solved in %f milliseconds' % solver.wall_time())
    print('Problem solved in %d iterations' % solver.iterations())
    print('Problem solved in %d branch-and-bound nodes' % solver.nodes())
else:
    print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')

denoms=[x[0].solution_value().as_integer_ratio()[1], x[1].solution_value().as_integer_ratio()[1],
       x[2].solution_value().as_integer_ratio()[1]]
scaling_factor=lcmm(*denoms) #a method to get the least common multiple
coeff=[scaling_factor*x[0].solution_value(), scaling_factor*x[1].solution_value(),
       scaling_factor*x[2].solution_value()]
```

This should return [1,0.5, 1] as the optimal solution, which becomes [2,1,2] after scaling.

(1) In my implementation, the solver does not find an optimal solution. Why is that?

(2) Is there a simpler way to get to the least positive integer solution?

Comment: I updated my answer to have what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues in your code.

With the line:

```
x[j] = solver.IntVar(0.0, infinity, 'x[%i]' % j)
```

You are saying that the optimizer must produce integers. However, the answer to your example was going to give x2 as 0.5, so it will fail to give the optimal solution. Try:

```
x[j] = solver.NumVar(0.0, infinity, 'x[%i]' % j)
```

Which allows floats. Then you can multiply it up to ints later.

Another issue, you set each constraint with:

```
constraint = solver.Constraint(0, data['bounds'][i], '')
```

Which means the lower bound for this expression is 0, and the upper bound is the `bound` value in your data structure. However, for your third constraint, this would be like saying `0 <= x1 <= 1` (bounds[2] is 1). However, you wanted to set this as an equality, not a range from 0 to some bound. You can replace the line with

```
constraint = solver.Constraint(data['bounds'][i], data['bounds'][i], '')
```

To  guarantee that the value is exactly what you want. You can also rename "bounds" to "target" to make it more clear that this isn't an upper or lower bound, but an exact target you want.

Finally, I don't see where you run `status = solver.Solve()` in your code. It should be right before you check `status` in that if/else.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologies, I typed the first constraint wrong. The one above is shown as just an example, and I want to extend this approach to others. While the algebra is simple on paper, how would one do this programmatically, where the number of variables and number of equations are not known before hand.

Comment: @user2657817 Found the issues, editing now.

Answer (score -2):

I think below code will give the solution, only trick we have to do is to set upper and lower bound between .5 to infinite. This may not be perfect code, but I am getting your answer with this code.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

obj_fun = lambda x: (x[0]+ x[1]+ x[2])

constraint = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  2*x[0] - 2*x[2]},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: 2*x[1]-x[2]})


bound = ((.5, None), (.5, None),(.5,None))
res = minimize(obj_fun, (2, 0,0), method='SLSQP', bounds=bound,
               constraints=constraint)

res
```

Comment: This returns an error that 'Objective function must return a scalar.' Also, to help generalize this approach, how can I adapt this code to avoid explicitly writing out each constraint.